# Ajuda com conexão ao banco de dados sql server 2008 e android

Tags: java, android, sql-server

Fiz, seguindo um tutorial, a conexão do Android Studio com o SQL Server 2008 r2 (já existente), com o qual eu consegui fazer a conexão normalmente, só que estou com um problema. Eu consigo fazer a conexão com o banco caso a conexão com o banco seja bem sucedida (acesso à porta, internet ok, etc). Caso eu não consiga acesso ao banco (acesso à porta negada ou falta de internet no PC servidor), o programa entra em uma tela preta como se ficasse tentando conectar ao banco e só depois de um tempo ele me retorna um erro.

Olha o código que eu uso:

**Conexão Dao**

```
public class ConexaoDao {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection dbConnect(ObjetoConexao objConexao) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String connectionUrl = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" +
                    objConexao.db_connect_string + ";" +
                    "databaseName=" + objConexao.db_name + ";user="
                    + objConexao.db_userid +
                    ";password=" + objConexao.db_password + ";";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);


            return conn;

        }


            catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf){
                System.out.println ("Classe JDBC Driver nao encontrada.");
                return null;
            }
            catch(SQLException sql){
                System.out.println ("Erro ao se conectar com o banco de dados.");


                return null;
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println (e.getMessage());
                return null;

            }
    }
}
```

**Classe onde faço a pesquisa**

```
public class Dao_PcCampestre extends Context{



    public String nomeTabela()  {

        String nomeResTorres = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "ronaldesantos.hopto.org:1433";
        objConexao.db_name = "Barbacena2";
        objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
        objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);



        if (conn == null) {

            nomeResTorres = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";



        } else if (conn != null) try {
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            String queryString = "select TOP 1 Area ,Source,Message from Alarmes Where AREA = 'POÇO CAMPESTRE' AND Source ='xo_Alarmes.Falta_Energia'  order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";
            ResultSet rs;

            rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);

            if (rs.next()) {

                nomeResTorres = rs.getString("Message");



            }

            rs.close();


        } catch (SQLException e) {



            System.out.println (e.getMessage());
            return null;



        }


        return nomeResTorres;

    }




    public String nomeTabela2()  {
        String nomeResTorres2 = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "ronaldesantos.hopto.org:1433";
        objConexao.db_name = "Barbacena2";
        objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
        objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);


        if (conn == null)  {

            nomeResTorres2 = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";

            return ""+ nomeResTorres2;

        }else if (conn != null) try {
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            String queryString = "select TOP 1 Code from Tbl_Comunicacao_Pc_Campestre where Situacao = 'Recepção (RX) - Aguardando' or Situacao =  'Recepção (RX) - OK' or Situacao =  'Recepção (RX) - Erro'   order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";
            ResultSet rs;

            rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);


            if (rs.next()) {

                nomeResTorres2 = rs.getString("Code");

                if (nomeResTorres2.equals("255")) {

                    nomeResTorres2 = "Aguardando Recepção";


                } else if (nomeResTorres2.equals("0")) {

                    nomeResTorres2 = "Recepção OK";


                } else if (nomeResTorres2.equals("4")) {

                    nomeResTorres2 = "Recepção OK";


                } else if (nomeResTorres2.equals("1")) {

                    nomeResTorres2 = "Falha na Recepção";


                }

                rs.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {


            System.out.println (e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
        return ""+ nomeResTorres2;


    }


    public String nomeTabela3()  {
        String nomeResTorres3 = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "ronaldesantos.hopto.org:1433";
        objConexao.db_name = "Barbacena2";
        objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
        objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);



        if (conn == null)  {

            nomeResTorres3 = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";

            return  ""+ nomeResTorres3;

        }else  if (conn != null) try {
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            String queryString = "select TOP 1 Area,Source,Message from Alarmes Where AREA = 'POÇO CAMPESTRE' AND Source ='xo_Alarmes.Presenca'  order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";
            ResultSet rs;

            rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);



            if (rs.next()) {

                nomeResTorres3 = rs.getString("Message");
            }

            rs.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println (e.getMessage());
            return null;

        }
        return ""+ nomeResTorres3;


    }




    public String nomeTabela5() {
        String nomeResTorres5 = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "ronaldesantos.hopto.org:1433";
        objConexao.db_name = "Barbacena2";
        objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
        objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);




        if (conn == null)  {

            nomeResTorres5 = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";

            return "" + nomeResTorres5;

        }       else if (conn != null) try {
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            String queryString = "select TOP 1 Area ,Source,Message from Alarmes Where AREA = 'POÇO CAMPESTRE' AND Source ='xo_Alarmes.Sobrecarga'  order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";
            ResultSet rs;

            rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);


            if (rs.next()) {

                nomeResTorres5 = rs.getString("Message");



            }

            rs.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {



            System.out.println (e.getMessage());
            return null;

        }
        return "" + nomeResTorres5;

    }

    public String nomeTabela6() {
        String nomeResTorres6 = "";
        ConexaoDao conexao = new ConexaoDao();
        ObjetoConexao objConexao = new ObjetoConexao();
        objConexao.db_connect_string = "flexsas.hopto.org:1433";
        objConexao.db_name = "Barbacena2";
        objConexao.db_userid = "sa";
        objConexao.db_password = "flextelecom";
        Connection conn = conexao.dbConnect(objConexao);


        if (conn == null)  {

            nomeResTorres6 = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";

            return "" + nomeResTorres6;

        }else     if (conn != null) {
            try {
                Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
                String queryString = "select TOP 1 Estado  from Tbl_Acionamentos_Pc_Campestre  order By E3TimeStamp DESC ";
                ResultSet rs;

                rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);


                if (rs.next()) {

                    nomeResTorres6 = rs.getString("Estado");
                }


                rs.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {



                System.out.println (e.getMessage());
                return null;




            }
        }
        return "" + nomeResTorres6;

    }
```

Neste caso clico em um botão que me leva à tela de resultados.

Caso ocorra problema com a conexão ao banco ele fica em processamento conforme o monitoramento no Android Studio (enquanto ele não percorre todas as pesquisa não me retorna nada).

```
06-22 12:00:40.373 2371-2377/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena W/art: Suspending all threads took: 16.647ms
06-22 12:01:09.469 2371-2382/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena W/art: Suspending all threads took: 6.838ms
06-22 12:01:09.476 2371-2382/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 7371(946KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(16KB) LOS objects, 23% free, 3MB/4MB, paused 10.003ms total 25.924ms
06-22 12:03:17.195 2371-2371/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena I/System.out: Erro ao se conectar com o banco de dados.
06-22 12:05:24.874 2371-2371/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena I/System.out: Erro ao se conectar com o banco de dados.
06-22 12:07:32.395 2371-2371/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena I/System.out: Erro ao se conectar com o banco de dados.
06-22 12:09:39.913 2371-2371/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena I/System.out: Erro ao se conectar com o banco de dados.
06-22 12:11:47.433 2371-2371/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena I/System.out: Erro ao se conectar com o banco de dados.
06-22 12:11:47.453 2371-2371/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena I/Choreographer: Skipped 38296 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-22 12:11:47.510 2371-2609/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-22 12:11:47.510 2371-2609/br.com.flextelecom.barbacena W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0x7f5184c0abc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Segue o `main`:

```
public class Act_Poco_Campestre extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btnFechar;
    private TextView tvNomeComunicacao;
    private ImageView ImgSinal;
    private ImageView ImgStatus;
    private TextView tvNomeStatus;
    private TextView tvNomePresenca;
    private ImageView ImgPresenca;
    private TextView tvNomeFalha;
    private ImageView Imgfalha;
    private TextView tvNomeEnergia;
    private ImageView ImgEnergia;


    String Aguardanando = "Aguardando Recepção";
    String Recepcao = "Recepção OK";
    String Falha = "Falha na Recepção";
    String PresencaAc = "Sensor Invasão Atuado";
    String PresencaN = "Sensor Invasão Desarmado";
    String FalhaAc = "Sobrecarga Motor";
    String FalhaN = "Rearme Sobrecarga";
    String StatusAc = "Ligado";
    String StatusN = "Desligado";
    String EnergiaAc = "Falta Enegia Eletrica";
    String EnergiaN = "Enegia Eletrica Restabelecida";
    String FalhaCon = "Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act__poco__campestre);


        btnFechar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFechar);
        btnFechar.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvNomeComunicacao = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeComunicacao);
        ImgSinal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgSinal);
        ImgStatus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgStatus);
        ImgPresenca = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgPresenca);
        tvNomePresenca = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomePresenca);
        Imgfalha = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgFalha);
        tvNomeFalha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeFalha);
        tvNomeStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeEstado);
        ImgEnergia = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImgEnergia);
        tvNomeEnergia = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNomeEnergia);
        Dao_PcCampestre  dao_pcCampestre1= new Dao_PcCampestre();
        Dao_PcCampestre  dao_pcCampestre2= new Dao_PcCampestre();
        Dao_PcCampestre  dao_pcCampestre3= new Dao_PcCampestre();
        Dao_PcCampestre  dao_pcCampestre4= new Dao_PcCampestre();
        Dao_PcCampestre  dao_pcCampestre5= new Dao_PcCampestre();


        String nomeEnergia = dao_pcCampestre1.nomeTabela();
        String nomeComunicacao = dao_pcCampestre2.nomeTabela2();
        String nomePresenca = dao_pcCampestre3.nomeTabela3();
        String nomeFalha = dao_pcCampestre4.nomeTabela5();
        String nomeAcionamento = dao_pcCampestre5.nomeTabela6();

        if (nomeComunicacao.equals(Aguardanando)) {

            tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFEED04"));
            tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + "Aguardando Recepção");
            ImgSinal.setImageResource(R.drawable.samarelo);


        } else if (nomeComunicacao.equals(Recepcao)) {

            tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + " Recepção OK");
            ImgSinal.setImageResource(R.drawable.sverde);

        } else if (nomeComunicacao.equals(Falha)) {

            tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
            tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + "Falha na Recepção");
            ImgSinal.setImageResource(R.drawable.svermelho);


        } else if (nomeComunicacao.equals(FalhaCon)){

            tvNomeComunicacao.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomeComunicacao.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");


        }

        if (nomePresenca.equals(PresencaN)) {

            tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomePresenca.setText("" + " Sensor Invasão Desarmado");
            ImgPresenca.setImageResource(R.drawable.presencaon);

        } else if (nomePresenca.equals(PresencaAc)) {

            tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
            tvNomePresenca.setText("" + "Sensor Invasão Atuado");
            ImgPresenca.setImageResource(R.drawable.presenca);


    } else if (nomePresenca.equals(FalhaCon)) {

            tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomePresenca.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");

        } else if (nomePresenca.isEmpty()) {

            tvNomePresenca.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomePresenca.setText("" + " Sensor Invasão Desarmado");
            ImgPresenca.setImageResource(R.drawable.presencaon);

        }

        if (nomeFalha.equals(FalhaN)){

            tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomeFalha.setText("" + " Rearme Falha");

        } else if (nomeFalha.equals(FalhaAc)) {

            tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
            tvNomeFalha.setText("" + "Falha Motor");
            Imgfalha.setImageResource(R.drawable.falhaon);


        }else if (nomeFalha.equals(FalhaCon)){

            tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomeFalha.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");


        }else if (nomeFalha.isEmpty()){

            tvNomeFalha.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomeFalha.setText("" + " Rearme Falha");
        }


        if (nomeEnergia.equals(EnergiaN)){

            tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + " Enegia Eletrica Ok");
            ImgEnergia.setImageResource(R.drawable.energiaon);

        } else if (nomeEnergia.equals(EnergiaAc)) {

            tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
            tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + "Falta Enegia Eletrica");
            ImgEnergia.setImageResource(R.drawable.energiaoff);

        } else if (nomeEnergia.equals(FalhaCon)){

                tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
                tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");

        } else if (nomeEnergia.isEmpty()){

            tvNomeEnergia.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomeEnergia.setText("" + " Enegia Eletrica OK");
            ImgEnergia.setImageResource(R.drawable.energiaon);
        }


        if (nomeAcionamento.equals(StatusN)){

            tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
            tvNomeStatus.setText("" + " Poço Desligado");
            ImgStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.pocooff);

        } else if (nomeAcionamento.equals(StatusAc)) {

            tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomeStatus.setText("" + "Poço Ligado");
            ImgStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.pocon);


        } else if (nomeAcionamento.equals(FalhaCon)){

            tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF60FB07"));
            tvNomeStatus.setText("" + " Não foi possivel se conectar ao banco de dados");

        } else if (nomeAcionamento.isEmpty()){

            tvNomeStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFC120E"));
            tvNomeStatus.setText("" + " Poço Desligado");
            ImgStatus.setImageResource(R.drawable.pocooff);
        }



    }




    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Não seria melhor um webservice? Nota: Android-studio é apenas o IDE e de nada interfere na lógica do teu código, como a pergunta não é um problema com o IDE e sim com o desenvolvimento eu editei a pergunta. Recomendo que aprenda a usar a marcação direito pro código não ficar deformando na pergunta e NÃO USE ***"CAIXA ALTA"*** SEM NECESSIDADE.

Comment: Posta o código da classe MainActivity também, ou melhor veja outras perguntas que tem bastante votos e veja como eles perguntam ou leia este link pra aprender a expor o seu problema de maneira que as pessoas entendam: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve caso contrário será dificil alguém lhe ajudar. Entenda como criticas construtivas

Comment: Guilherme Eu Sou iniciante e de incio não posso usar webservice.

Comment: Use a marcação de texto corretamente por favor, se não a cada edição sua alguém vai ter que corrigir.

Answer (score 1):

Independente da arquitetura (usar webservices ou não), a tela preta é porque você não está utilizando uma thread separada para realizar operações de rede por exemplo. Quando a resposta é rápida para poder fazer a conexão, consultas seu aplicativo funciona normalmente, quando há problemas, dá mesmo o delay de interface porque você está rodando isso na thread principal de UI, como costumamos dizer.

Em sua activity, você pode criar uma classe inner que estende de AsyncTask para realizar esse processo de conexão e ter melhores resultados. Evite rodar seu aplicativo em "strict mode".

Exemplo de uso da AsyncTask para você estudar melhor:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Edição: Exemplo prático genérico (adapte à sua necessidade de banco de dados).

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.System;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class AsyncTaskActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button btn;
    private Integer total;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            new ExemploAsync().execute();
            break;
        }
    }

    private class ExemploAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    total = total * i;
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.interrupted();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           //faça o que quiser com o total...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            total = 1;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Mateus sou bem iniciante . teria como me dar um exemplo neste código que eu tenho de como fazer isto, ou pelo menos para a aplicação casso isto ocorra?

Comment: @Mateus uma AsyncTask com uma progressbar, o que você acha?

Comment: @PauloHenriqueNeryOliveira neste caso não funcionaria. Medir os pacotes trafegados entre o banco e a aplicação é um trabalho que, nesse contexto eu dispensaria.

Comment: @RonaldoSantos exemplo genérico para você entender como funciona e depois adaptá-lo a sua necessidade.